# Retrieve JSON data into class array

Tags: json, angular, http, ionic-framework, angular8

I'm trying to retrieve the data from the file below, return a class object with the json values and push it into the class array above to display it as hard-coded json data, The current error is being unable to assign Exercise[] to Exercise. I am new to coding and would be really thankful to someone who could lend a helping hand.

```
export class ExerciseService {
  exercises: Exercise[] = []
  completedEx: Exercise[] = []
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    // this.exercises = [
    //    new Exercise('pull-ups', 3, 5, '1/1/2020', '13:00', 'assets/pullups.jpg', 'pull-ups'),
    //    new Exercise('push-ups', 3, 20, '2/2/2020', '14:00', 'assets/pushups.jpg', 'push-ups'),
    //    new Exercise('sit-ups', 3, 30, '3/3/2020', '15:00', 'assets/situps.jpg', 'sit-ups')
    // ]
     this.getExerciseData().subscribe(data=> this.exercises.push(data))
  }

  getExercises(): Exercise[] {
    return this.exercises;
  }


  getExerciseData(){
    return this.http.get("/assets/data/exerciseData.json").pipe
    (map(response => Object.keys(response["exercises"]).map(function(key, index){
      let row = response["exercises"][key]
      return new Exercise(key, row["sets"], row["reps"], row["date"], row["time"], row["image"], key)
    })))
  }


//json file
{
    "exercises": {
        "Pull-ups": {
            "name": "Pull-ups",
            "sets": 3,
            "reps": 6,
            "date": "2/2/2020",
            "time": "16:00",
            "image": "assets/pullups.jpg",
            "id": "Pull-ups"
        },
        "Push-ups": {
            "name": "Push-ups",
            "sets": 3,
            "reps": 20,
            "date": "10/2/2020",
            "time": "14:00",
            "image": "assets/pushups.jpg",
            "id": "Push-ups"
        },
        "Sit-ups": {
            "name": "Sit-ups",
            "sets": 5,
            "reps": 30,
            "date": "12/2/2020",
            "time": "13:00",
            "image": "assets/situps.jpg",
            "id": "Sit-ups"
        }
    }
}


//exercise class
export class Exercise {

    name: string
    reps: number
    sets: number
    date: string
    time: string
    image: string
    id: string

    constructor(name: string, sets: number, reps: number, date: string, time: string, image: string, id?: string) {
        this.name = name
        this.sets = sets
        this.reps = reps
        this.date = date
        this.time = time
        this.image = image
        this.id = id
    }
}
```

Comment: what is constructor of exercise class?

Comment: @AakashGarg sorry i completely forgot to add it, i've added it now

Comment: The data returned from `getExerciseData()` function is already an array with three objects of `Exercise` class. You need to do `data => this.exercises = [...this.exercises, ...data]` in the subscription. More on spread operator (`...`) here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your constructor code To :-

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
     this.getExerciseData().subscribe(data=> {
        this.exercises = [...this.exercises, ...data]);
     });
  }
```

Change your getExcercise Method To :-

```
getExerciseData(){
    return this.http.get("/assets/data/exerciseData.json").pipe
    (map(response => Object.keys(response["exercises"]).map((key, index) =>{
      let row = response["exercises"][key]
      return new Exercise(key, row["sets"], row["reps"], row["date"], row["time"], row["image"], key)
    })))
  }
```

Comment: Hi Aakash, the exercises array still doesn't populate with the JSON objects,

I am trying to use the getExercises() function on another tab

Comment: updated statement, forgot to assign it back to exercises :P

Comment: still not populating for some reason

Comment: copy the whole statement, and console.log as seconds statement of subscript. data will be there.

Comment: I tried logging the exercises array and its till empty even on the next page

Edit: sorry if I seem particulary slow, this is my first few months of coding, I appreciate all the help though

Comment: what do you mean by next page, and i have also changed your getExerciseData method, copy that as well. and tell the whole scenario. try to print this.exercises inside subscribe of same service. you can see changed array.

Comment: this is my exerciseService file, I have another file which is the tabs.ts file which retrieves the array from this file as well

Comment: first try to print inside subscribe, and see if exercises is getting values. what you are asking becomes totally a different question.

Comment: what you were doing wrong in tabs is trying to get the data even before your subscription was complete. resolving that is a different question altogether. your current question is solved.

Comment: Yeap ur right, i've marked ur answer as solution and I'll go work on fixing the tabs part. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Aakash, I worked around your solution and managed to come to the solutin I was looking for, thanks so much for the help!